# An error occurred while calling o91.parquet. : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I used this simple python code with focus on spark.sql:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('jist-test').getOrCreate()
myDF = spark.read.parquet("v3io://projects/fs-demo-example/FeatureStore/vct_all_other_basic")
myDF.show(3)
```

and I got this exception:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-fd92fbf397a3> in <module>
      1 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('jist-test').getOrCreate()
----> 2 myDF = spark.read.parquet("v3io://projects/fs-demo-example/FeatureStore/vct_all_other_basic")
/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in parquet(self, *paths, **options)
    299                        int96RebaseMode=int96RebaseMode)
    300 
--> 301         return self._df(self._jreader.parquet(_to_seq(self._spark._sc, paths)))
    302 
    303     def text(self, paths, wholetext=False, lineSep=None, pathGlobFilter=None,
/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1321         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 
   1324         for temp_arg in temp_args:
/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o91.parquet.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java
...
```

It happened from time to time in pyspark version 3.2.1. Do you know, how to avoid this mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I caught it. It is possible to minimize occurrence or remove this exception based on regular closing or killing spark session.

See updated part of the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

with SparkSession.builder.appName('jist-test').getOrCreate() as spark:
    myDF = spark.read.parquet("v3io://projects/fs-demo-example/FeatureStore/vct_all_other_basic")
    myDF.show(3)
```

or

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

try:
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('jist-test').getOrCreate()
    myDF = spark.read.parquet("v3io://projects/fs-demo-example/FeatureStore/vct_all_other_basic")
    myDF.show(3)
finally:
    spark.stop()
```